# MongoDB mass update inserting data from one document to another one

Tags: mongodb

I'm still learning about MongoDB and I would like to know if someone could help me with the situation I'm facing.

I'm taking over a DB structure that has been created like a relational DB abd I would like to embed a full document (instead of a reference only to the document) into all my documents.

Let me try to explain the best I can:

I have an activity table that references a user using its userID

```
activity : {
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5324a18d3061650002030000") 
}
```

user_id is the primary id of another document called user.

user:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5324a18d3061650002030000"),
    "active" : true,
    "birth_date" : ISODate("1980-03-25T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

What I would like to do is to insert my user into my activity document:

activity : {

```
      "user_id" : ObjectId("5324a18d3061650002030000") 
      user:
     {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5324a18d3061650002030000"),
          "active" : true,
          "birth_date" : ISODate("1980-03-25T00:00:00.000Z")
     }
```

}

I would like to do that for all my activity documents (knowing that they all reference different users of course), what would be the best way to do that please?

Thanks a lot guys !!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be simpler like this:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    db.activity.update({user_id: doc._id}, {$set:{user:doc}});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I'm trying to do this update using the MongoDB shell though... can it be done without using a JS object ?

Comment: @Emdis, if you don't buffer documents of `user` collection, perhaps you have to execute every query from `user` collection of database for a single update, that will be very slow.